# Which English translation to use for shnayim mikrah?

Tags: product-recommendation, translation, pentateuch-chumash, shnayim-mikra

According to some *poskim*, a person can be *yotzei* his obligation of *shnayim mikrah ve'echad targum* by reading the *pesukim* twice and an English translation once. If I remember correctly, this is only true if the English translation is not only a technical translation of the Hebrew words but rather also includes an explanation of the Hebrew (to whatever extent that's possible when claiming to be a translation and not a commentary).

The question is, what English translations are out there that could be considered to do a good job of not only translating but also of including an explanation such that the translation could be used as "*targum*"?

Comment: What about Artscroll's English translation of Targum Onkelus?

Comment: I'd imagine that any translation that is readable as opposed to a literal translation of every word would constitute a viable translation for shnayim mikra.